# Pass multi-word arguments to a bash function

Tags: bash, parameters, cpu-word, split

Inside a bash script function, I need to work with the command-line arguments of the script, and also with another list of arguments. So I'm trying to pass two argument lists to a function, the problem is that multi-word arguments get split.

```
function params()
{
    for PARAM in $1; do
        echo "$PARAM"
    done

    echo .

    for ITEM in $2; do
        echo "$ITEM"
    done
}

PARAMS="$@"
ITEMS="x y 'z t'"
params "$PARAMS" "$ITEMS"
```

calling the script gives me

```
myscript.sh a b 'c d'
a
b
c
d
.
x
y
'z
t'
```

Since there are two lists they must be passed as a whole to the function, the question is, how to iterate the elements while respecting multi-word items enclosed in single quotes 'c d' and 'z t'?

The workaround that I have (see below) makes use of BASH_ARGV so I need to pass just a single list to the function. However I would like to get a better understanding of what's going on and what's needed to make the above work.

```
function params()
{
    for PARAM in "${BASH_ARGV[@]}"; do
        echo "$PARAM"
    done

    echo .

    for ITEM in "$@"; do
        echo "$ITEM"
    done
}

params x y 'z t'
```

calling the script gives me

```
myscript.sh a b 'c d'
c d
b
a
.
x
y
z t
```

... Which is how I need it (except that first list is reversed, but that would be tolerable I guess)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
function params()
{
   arg=("$@")

   for ((i=1;i<=$1;i++)) ;do
       echo "${arg[i]}"
   done

   echo .

   for ((;i<=$#-$1+2;i++)) ;do
       echo "${arg[i]}"
   done
}

items=(w x 'z t')
params $# "$@" "${items[@]}"
```

Assuming you call your script with args `a b 'c d'`, the output is:

```
a
b
c d
.
x
y
z t
```

Comment: I see... so you are passing items individually to the function. Seems to me that the only place where bash splits a string into items while respecting quotes is when interpreting a command line.

Comment: The nature of passing the array elements as `"${items[@]}"` (in double quotes) has the effect of sending each element as `"${items[0]}"  "${items[1]}" "${items[2]} ...` etc ... if you passed it as `${items[@]}` you would get word splitting with elements which contained whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

Peter.O's answer above works fine, and this is an addendum to it, with an example.

I needed a function or script that would take multi-word arguments, that would then be used to search the list of running processes and kill those that matched one of the arguments.  The following script does that.  The function `kill_processes_that_match_arguments` only needs one `for` loop, because my need was only to iterate over the set of all arguments to the function.  Tested to work.

```
#!/bin/bash

function kill_processes_that_match_arguments()
{
    arg=("$@")
    unset PIDS_TO_BE_KILLED

    for ((i=0;i<$#;i++))
    do
        unset MORE_PIDS_TO_KILL
        MORE_PIDS_TO_KILL=$( ps gaux | grep "${arg[i]}" | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{ print $2 }' )
        if [[ $MORE_PIDS_TO_KILL ]]; then
            PIDS_TO_BE_KILLED="$MORE_PIDS_TO_KILL $PIDS_TO_BE_KILLED"
        fi
    done

    if [[ $PIDS_TO_BE_KILLED ]]; then
        kill -SIGKILL $PIDS_TO_BE_KILLED
        echo 'Killed processes:' $PIDS_TO_BE_KILLED
    else
        echo 'No processes were killed.'
    fi
}

KILL_THESE_PROCESSES=('a.single.word.argument' 'a multi-word argument' '/some/other/argument' 'yet another')
kill_processes_that_match_arguments "${KILL_THESE_PROCESSES[@]}"
```